# CSS grid with same height columns

Tags: css, css-grid

I have these 3 columns, and it was built using a grid.
How do I make the grey background the same height for all columns?
Ideally not changing this html structure and using css only.

I tried making the div "content" 100% height but doesn't work.

Thanks!

```css
   .block-news__container {
      max-width: 1280px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      column-gap: 30px;
    }
    
    .block-news__container ._item {
      width: 100%;
    }
    
    .block-news__container ._item ._image {
      width: 100%;
      height: 310px;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    
    .block-news__container ._item ._content {
      background-color: #ccc;
      padding: 50px 30px 80px;
      position: relative;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="block-news__container">
        <div class="_item"><img alt="image-news-1" class="_image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
            <div class="_content">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
                <p>tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="icon-arrow-green" width="30" src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/503/684/png-clipart-right-arrow-simple-rounded-arrow-right-icons-logos-emojis-arrows.png"> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="_item"><img alt="image-news-2" class="_image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
            <div class="_content">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                <p>tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit </p><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="icon-arrow-green" width="30" src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/503/684/png-clipart-right-arrow-simple-rounded-arrow-right-icons-logos-emojis-arrows.png"> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="_item"><img alt="image-news-3" class="_image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
            <div class="_content">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
                <p>tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in </p><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="icon-arrow-green" width="30" src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/503/684/png-clipart-right-arrow-simple-rounded-arrow-right-icons-logos-emojis-arrows.png"> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: @Paulie_D, thanks. I have placed the code here.

Answer (score -1):

Make the height of the `.block-news__container ._item ._content` class with manual value. you can fix the height of the content container as you desired to get same height for all the containers.

```css
   .block-news__container {
      max-width: 1280px;
      margin: 0 auto;
      position: relative;
      z-index: 1;
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
      column-gap: 30px;
    }
    
    .block-news__container ._item {
      width: 100%;
    
    }
    
    .block-news__container ._item ._image {
      width: 100%;
      height: 310px;
      object-fit: cover;
    }
    
    .block-news__container ._item ._content {
      background-color: #ccc;
      padding: 50px 30px 80px;
      position: relative;
      margin-top: 10px;
     height:250px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="block-news__container">
        <div class="_item"><img alt="image-news-1" class="_image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
            <div class="_content">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
                <p>tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="icon-arrow-green" width="30" src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/503/684/png-clipart-right-arrow-simple-rounded-arrow-right-icons-logos-emojis-arrows.png"> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="_item"><img alt="image-news-2" class="_image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
            <div class="_content">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h3>
                <p>tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit </p><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="icon-arrow-green" width="30" src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/503/684/png-clipart-right-arrow-simple-rounded-arrow-right-icons-logos-emojis-arrows.png"> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="_item"><img alt="image-news-3" class="_image" src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff">
            <div class="_content">
                <h3>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod</h3>
                <p>tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in </p><a href="#" target="_blank"><img alt="icon-arrow-green" width="30" src="https://e7.pngegg.com/pngimages/503/684/png-clipart-right-arrow-simple-rounded-arrow-right-icons-logos-emojis-arrows.png"> </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: The height can't be fixed, it needs to accommodate de different content sizes.

Answer (score -2):

vertical size is based on content or specific size
you can add height: 300px (or whatever measurement you desire) to ensure the same size